# Kali Linux 2 on Raspberry Pi B - SSH autostart problems

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh, kali-linux

I recently got a Raspberry Pi model B and I decided to install Kali Linux 2 on it. The only problem I'm getting is SSH services (OpenSSH) won't start on boot no matter what I try, making it impossible to run it headless, and leaving me with a mass of wires. Any ideas why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: is there anything related in boot logs?

Comment: When it boots it says something about "Stopping OpenBSD SSH services"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and found a solution by reading through this thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=86950

First I did:

```
update-rc.d ssh defaults
update-rc.d ssh enable
```

and also I did:

```
systemctl enable ssh.
```

The last command resulted in this:

```
Synchronizing state of ssh.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ssh
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service → /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service.
```